# How do you detect the completion of an asynchronous couchdb event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, couchdb

I'm having a bit of trouble with promises using the jquery couchdb library.

I'm not sure how to detect when a load event has finished. Here is my code:

```
var ingredients;
  function loadIngredients() {
      try {
          var deferred = $.Deferred();
          $.couch.db("ingredients").allDocs({
              success: function (result) {
                  ingredients = result;
                  deferred.resolve();
                  return deferred.promise();
              }
          });
      }
      catch (err) {
          alert(err.message + " loadingredients");
          deferred.reject();
      }
  }

  try
  {
      var promise = loadIngredients();
      promise.done(function(){(alert("done"))});
  }
  catch (err) {
      alert(err.message + " execution");
  }
```

I'm a little bit fried at the moment so I apologise if this doesn't make sense.

I just need to know how to detect when the $.couch.db("ingredients").allDocs() event has finished. I can't get my head around the syntax of a promise to do that though. 
Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the promise from loadIngredients() and assign method to done() as shown below.

So loadIngedients() creates a deferred and returns it (as a promise) but only when the allDocs() success function resolves the deferred will the promise.done() method be called thus triggering the 'done' alert...

Note that you would want to possibly handle the rejected scenario in the caller of loadIngredients() potentially also. Use the fail() method off of the promise to do this. You can just chain it off the done() method if needed as shown below

```
var ingredients;

function loadIngredients() {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();

  try {
      $.couch.db("ingredients").allDocs({
          success: function (result) {
              ingredients = result;
              deferred.resolve();
          }
      });
  }
  catch (err) {
      alert(err.message + " loadingredients");
      deferred.reject();
  }
  return deferred.promise();
}

try
{
    var promise = loadIngredients()
    promise.done(function(){(alert("done"))}).fail(function() { alert('FAIL!'); });
}
catch (err) {
    alert(err.message + " execution");
}
```

Comment: You are a saint. Thank you.
I had a feeling I was close :)

Comment: No problems, glad it's helpful.